# JPA Entity Creation

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jpa-2.1

I have been trying to create JPA entity using schema of [Mysql Sample Database](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sample-database.aspx/) , [JPA tools of Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/docs/3.2/user_guide/tasks006.htm) JPA entites are generated using i am having for establishing entity relationship for below scenarios and tables

1. Employee Table : Employee tables has field **reportsto** which refers back to employee i.e one employee reports to another employee
2. Office Table: One office can have more then one Employee

Below are JPA Entities :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employees")
@NamedQuery(name="Employee.findAll", query="SELECT e FROM Employee e")
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String email;

    private String extension;

    private String firstName;

    private String jobTitle;

    private String lastName;

    //bi-directional one-to-one association to Customer
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="employee")
    private Customer customer;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Office
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="officeCode", referencedColumnName="officeCode")
    private Office office;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Employee
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="reportsTo", referencedColumnName="employeeNumber")
    private Employee employee;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Employee
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="employee")
    private List<Employee> employees;

}
```

Table Description

```
CREATE TABLE `employees` (
  `employeeNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `firstName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `extension` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `officeCode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `reportsTo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jobTitle` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`employeeNumber`),
  KEY `reportsTo` (`reportsTo`),
  KEY `officeCode` (`officeCode`),
  CONSTRAINT `employees_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`reportsTo`) REFERENCES `employees` (`employeeNumber`),
  CONSTRAINT `employees_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`officeCode`) REFERENCES `offices` (`officeCode`)
)
```

When app loads we get below error message

```
referencedColumnNames(employeeNumber) of com.train.model.Employee.employee referencing com.train.model.Employee not mapped to a single property
```

when i add field employeeNumber and generate getters and setters , i get below error

```
referencedColumnNames(officeCode) of com.train.model.Employee.office referencing com.train.model.Office not mapped to a single property
```

Office JPA Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="offices")
@NamedQuery(name="Office.findAll", query="SELECT o FROM Office o")
public class Office implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String addressLine1;

    private String addressLine2;

    private String city;

    private String country;

    private String phone;

    private String postalCode;

    private String state;

    private String territory;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Employee
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="office")
    private List<Employee> employees;

}

Table Description


CREATE TABLE `offices` (
  `officeCode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `addressLine1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `addressLine2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `postalCode` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `territory` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`officeCode`)
)
```

Why employee entity complains of not having officeCode and what is right entity for Employee and Office

Comment: Do you really have to use entity mappings, I find that I sleep much better at night when I reference other related entities by id:Long

Comment: can you please provide example